# is it possible for one object be two types/classes in python

Tags: python, class, types, tree

I'm trying to implement binary tree using python so I constructed a Node class and a Tree class which takes Nodes as root and leaves. This is the part where I have problems with:

```
def BFS(self):
    s = " "
    currentD = deque()
    nextD = deque()
    currentD.append(self.root)
    while currentD:
        while currentD:

            r = currentD.popleft()
            print type(r)
            print isinstance(r, Node)
            print isinstance(r, Tree)

            if not r.isVisited():
                r.visit()    
                s += " " + str(r.get_val())
                if r.get_left():
                    nextD.append(r.get_left())
                if r.get_right():
                    nextD.append(r.get_right())
        #currentD should be empty now           
        s += "\n"
        swap(currentD, nextD) 
    self.root.refresh()    
    return s

def __str__(self):
    return self.BFS()
```

The problem I have now is when I tried to use two deques to do BFS and print the tree, the object r obtained(using popleft()) by currentD is supposed to a Node in the Tree. However, I got the error message that "AttributeError: 'Tree' object has no attribute 'isVisited'". If I use the attribute of Tree, it would give me another "AttributeError" that 'Node' object has no attribute ... .So I tried to check the type of this r, and it seems that it belongs both of the classes. This is the message:

```
 <class '__main__.Node'>
 True
 False
 <class '__main__.Tree'>
 False
 True
```

If this is not the problem caused by other bugs, could anyone explain a little to me about this python feature? And in this case, how could I "tell" the program that this is a Node instead of a Tree? 
I'll put the class for Node and Tree here just in case. Thank you very much!

```
    class Node(object):
        def __init__(self,val = None, left = None, right = None, visited = False):
            self.val = val
            self.left = left
            self.right = right
            self.visited = visited
        def get_val(self):
            return self.val
        def get_left(self):
            return self.left
        def get_right(self):
            return self.right
        def set_left(self, lItem):
            self.left = lItem
        def set_right(self, rItem):
            self.right = rItem
        def isVisited(self):
            return self.visited
        def visit(self):
            self.visited = True
        def refresh(self):
            self.visited = False

        def add_BST(self, item):
            node = Node(item)
            if not self.val:
                self.val = item
            elif self.val < item:
                if not self.right:
                     self.right = node
                else:
                     self.right.add_BST(item)
            else:
                if not self.left:
                     self.left = node
                else:
                     self.left.add_BST(item)

class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, root = None):
        self.root = root

    def get_root(self):
        return self.root
    def add(self, item):
        self.root.add_BST(item)
    def BFS(self):
        s = " "
        currentD = deque()
        nextD = deque()
        currentD.append(self.root)
        while currentD:
            while currentD:

                r = currentD.popleft()
                print type(r)
                print isinstance(r, Node)
                print isinstance(r, Tree)

                if not r.isVisited():
                    r.visit()    
                    s += " " + str(r.get_val())
                    if r.get_left():
                        nextD.append(r.get_left())
                    if r.get_right():
                        nextD.append(r.get_right())
            #currentD should be empty now           
            s += "\n"
            swap(currentD, nextD) 
        self.root.refresh()    
        return s

    def __str__(self):
        return self.BFS()
```

Comment: It seems you know how to properly format your code. So why didn't you format the code for your `Node` class?

Comment: One object isn't of two classes here; you have two different objects, from two different calls to popleft; one is a Node and one is a Tree. Obviously, that's a bug; your list should only contain Nodes.

Comment: Thank @Mr.goosberry for pointing out that, and I just edited.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I see! That's why the output for type() and isinstance() looks that. Thank you a lot!